# (Django) How do I make 'objects.get()' to work with an argument that exists?

Tags: python, django, authentication

I am trying to emulate Instagram login which takes either one of 'username', 'fullname', or 'email'.

views.py

```
class SignInView(View):
    def post(self, request):
        account_data = json.loads(request.body)

        try:
            if Account.objects.filter(email=account_data['email']).exists() or Account.objects.filter(username=account_data['username']).exists() or Account.objects.filter(fullname=account_data['fullname']).exists():
#############THIS IS WHERE IT NEEDS SOME ANSWER/WORK############################################
                account = Account.objects.get(email=account_data['email'])
#########################################################################################
                encoded_pw = account.password.encode('utf-8')
                encoded_input = account_data['password'].encode('utf-8')
                if bcrypt.checkpw(encoded_input, encoded_pw):
                    token = jwt.encode({ 'email' : account.email }, 'secret', algorithm='HS256').decode('utf-8')
                    return JsonResponse({ 'access_token' : token }, status=200)
                return HttpResponse(status=403)

            return HttpResponse(status=402)

        except KeyError:
            return JsonResponse({"message": "INVALID_KEYS"}, status=400)
```

I am trying to insert the account data into 'account' variable and the Account.objects.get() is supposed to take either one of 'email', 'username', or 'fullname' - which is decided by the user trying to log in. Is there any method in Python that automatically decides which data is the one given by the user?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a few things you could do here. Is it the case that only one and no more of these will be provided each login attempt? The simplest thing would probably be to do something like this:

```
if account_data['email']:
    account = Account.objects.get(email=account_data['email'])
elif account_data['username']:
    account = Account.objects.get(username=account_data['username'])
elif account_data['fullname']:
    account = Account.objects.get(fullname=account_data['fullname'])
```

You could also do something like this:

```
from django.db.models import Q

account = Account.objects.get(Q(Qemail=account_data['email'] | Q(username=account_data['username']) | Q(fullname=account_data['fullname']))
```

I'm not sure there's any real advantage in doing that over the first solution I've suggested.

Note that `objects.get()` is intended to return just one instance, and if it finds more than 1, it will throw an error. This means that if a user enters an email AND a username for a different user, then an error will be thrown. If your login form makes this possible, you should put the above in a `try: ... except MultipleObjectsReturned:` statement.

I would say however, that for the first line that you have it is worth doing this:

```
Account.objects.filter(Q(Qemail=account_data['email'] | Q(username=account_data['username']) | Q(fullname=account_data['fullname'])).exists()
```

The reason why it's an advantage to do this here, is that it is one hit to the database rather than 3 separate hits, which will be more efficient.

Comment: Please note that when the user enters both an existing username and a (different) existing email address, `Account.objects.get(Q(Qemail=account_data['email'] | Q(username=account_data['username']) | Q(fullname=account_data['fullname']))` will throw a `MultipleObjectsReturned` exception.

Comment: Yes, I'll clarify this in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the easiest way if you don't know what information you will receive is using regex. Email has @ and . in it and i think fullname should have at least one space in the middle. Code will probably looks like this:

```
import re

if re.match("[a-z0-9]+[\._]?[a-z0-9]+[@]\w+[.]\w+$",account_data["data"]):
    account = Account.objects.get(email=account_data['data'])
elif re.match("/s",account_data["data"]):
    account = Account.objects.get(fullname=account_data['data'])
else:
    account = Account.objects.get(username=account_data['data'])
```